# Git config: one fetch and two push destinations

Tags: git, heroku, egit

I am using EGit for version control in Eclipse. I'd like to have two remote Git repositories, one is Github and the other Heroku. The former is for the system development team, and the latter is only for deployment. I set the git `config` file as follows, but it doesn't work for both remotes.

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "github"]
    url = https://github.com/yltang52/airbus.git
    fetch = refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
    push = master:refs/heads/master
[remote "heroku"]
    url = https://git.heroku.com/airbus.git
    push = master:refs/heads/master
[branch "master"]
    remote = github
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

ps. `yltang52` is the github username and `airbus` is the project name.

One of the problems is that Git suggests to place the `.git` directory outside the project root directory, and this is what I am doing now. However, Heroku requires to place the directory in the project root directory.

When I create a `.git` directory in the project root directory (according to Heroku's deployment procedure), I can deploy the project to Heroku. But then when I try to commit and push to Github, all my files are marked for commit. Obviously, the two `.git` copies can't work together.

I'd like to integrate Heroku deployment into EGit. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to work directly with an Eclipse project compatible with Heroku, and *then* to add the GitHub remote repo reference.

that is what is described in "[How to push to multiple remote Git repositories using 1 Eclipse operation (killing 2 birds with 1 stone)](http://appirio.com/category/tech-blog/2013/10/push-multiple-remote-git-repositories-using-1-eclipse-operation-killing-2-birds-1-stone/)", using:

- Egit,
- the [Heroku plugin for Eclipse](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-heroku-eclipse).

That should give you an heroku app with the heroku remote url already configured, and for which you can configure those remote urls:

[image: https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/s0BexPSV1e7c_BEJ3aMlKxnLx1pO7wLgixSnvRoFcuE8fw2Jl99zaY2csJbSfVRg_c3Mnq6RRWjChCsF-apW3nnk39iSrrgeIDn6RzIsXCJDCp6CqEP-PCXRPQ]

You can add both push url (to the GitHub repo and to heroku):

[image: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/UtOL9MAzW35ZivE2lp-OQFEacg6Jl6avPX65Q79Na8raExYZcDhTXb5kTzM1MfzRVh54_o1wSCt73VoxYxLm9xZGq5uXKtxm_A6PQu2QOUe_si7FyB8NYSCkRg]

(You can configure the Fetch in the same manner)

From there, a "push to upstream" will push to both:

[image: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Rp1r1qmjeZjAs5ZSw0TfR426m1buWdX31SaWTwLpQdW-s5Ri5QSKMf__T1cZNZ4Uc_ImcAz_fGqhQQ0F5Xodax6BJKOqqF0iepV6LNBtvSyVlFnqA1PzJ9v21A]

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I installed Heroku plugin for Eclipse, but I encountered two problems when creating a new Heroku project: a) I am developing Django projects, but there seems no such project template, b) System error: Eclipse SSH key is not matching the SSH key(s) that is associated with your Heroku account.The solution (http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/others/tips/resolve-error-eclipse-ssh-key-is-not-matching-the-ssh-keys-that-is-associated-with-your-heroku-account/) does not apply because there is no local project yet.

Comment: @yltang52 I understand. could you try to use another heroku template, and import your django settings in it?

Comment: Tried that but I the SSH key mismatch problem is still there. How do I solve it?

Comment: @yltang52 if you have a local project, then the blog post you mention should help. But if not, try simply to do an ssh manually: that will trigger the same error message, and you will be able to register that host.